# Average time durations in google form populated google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, duration, formulas

I have a google sheet that is auto populated from a google form. There is a column with time durations:

[image]

When I try to average these durations I get the divide by zero error. I tried changing the cell format, but nothing works. And in fact, it wont change at all no matter what format I choose. I think the format is locked based on the form that is populating the sheet.

Any help on getting the average in a cell below the column?

Comment: Show the formulas you've tried. Also note that filling content in below a form response is not really recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Please try a formula of this kind:

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(1*(A1:A15)))/counta(A1:A15)
```

with formatting to suit.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are getting values as text.

`=ArrayFormula(AVERAGEIF(A1:A18*1,">0"))`

- `*1` converts text into a number
- condition `">0"` to skip empty cells, converted to 0.
- format the result as duration.