# Google sheets average a series of durations of the form MM:SS[.\d+]

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, average, spreadsheet, duration

I have tried the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51830531/average-time-durations-in-google-form-populated-google-sheet) and they didn't work. I have a series of durations of the form in regex `\d+:\d+[.\d+]`, where the part before the colon is the number of minutes of a duration, and after the colon is the number of seconds of the duration which usually includes a decimal point. This is a usual output from the stopwatch with laps on my android phone. I want to average the lap times. In any case a minimal example would be like shown in the image below.

As you can see, it doesn't work. I tried formatting the Duration fields as a duration and it still gave the division by zero error.

[image: A google sheets image with laps and their durations]
[image: Showing the formatting menu with the duration box ticked]

Comment: can you share your sample shet?

Comment: Sure: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZGBQ58YM-k-N2dDZj-UlyYMIPX-AV-zYJOsNa8V300A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you want to edit the sample file @player0?

Comment: nah, btw, you expect result of average to be 1:0.4 right?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I expect indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little bit simpler option:

```
=ArrayFormula(AVERAGE(TIMEVALUE("0:"&B2:B8)))
```

[image]

format result cell as:

[image]

Comment: You take the cake, basic. For other users, this still leaves the usable underlying numerical value in the cell. If you don't want to set a specified end of range: `=ArrayFormula(AVERAGE(IFERROR(TIMEVALUE("0:"&B2:B))))`  To keep the original formatting, just format the result cell this way: **Format > Number > More Formats > Custom number format >** *m:s.0*

Comment: @basic can you explain how it interprets the milliseconds correctly? If we put `.1` after the seconds we would expect a tenth of a second, but its seems here that that would be 1 millisecond, right?

Comment: @AngularOrbit no, that's not correct - here 0.1 is abbreviated to 0.100, which is one tenth of a second. Respectively, 0.01 is one hundredth and 0.001 is one millisecond

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(AVERAGE(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(
 FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>""), ".", ":"))), "[h]:m.s"))
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Can you explain how it works?

Comment: @AngularOrbit sure, first we FILTER rows with values to avoid errors. next we SUBSTITUTE dot with : to shift it into h:m:s so minutes becomes hours, seconds become minutes and decimal seconds become seconds. next we convert times into values with VALUE and run AVERAGE. and as last step we formatt it back the way it was with TEXT where we make duration out of hours which are in fact minutes. INDEX is for processing arrays instead of ArrayFormula - coz its shorter

Comment: When we substitute, the `.` with a `:`, doesn't this affect the base of the decimals?

Comment: @AngularOrbit depends. in some cases, it could affect it. added more accurate solution

Answer (score 1):

more accurate solution:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(AVERAGE(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(
 FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>""), ":")/24/60/{1,60}, 
 "select Col1+Col2"), "offset 1", 0)), "m:s.0"))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also can you swap the dot with the colon. The edit's too tiny to take effect.